# Implementation of Strategy Pattern (photo gallery example)

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns

I'm learning design patterns and I thought that it would be a good idea to make my examples of each pattern. This is [my example](https://github.com/NovaBG03/DesignPatternsExamples/tree/master/StrategyPatternExamples/Example1) of the Strategy Pattern. Can you tell me is it good and what to improve?

This is the Gallery class

```
    public class PhotoGallery
{
    private ICollection<string> photosNames;
    private IShareStrategy shareStrategy;


    public PhotoGallery()
    {
        this.photosNames = new List<string>();
    }


    public void AddPhoto(string photoName)
    {
        this.photosNames.Add(photoName);
    }

    private void SetShareStrategy(ShareStrategy strategy)
    {
        switch (strategy)
        {
            case ShareStrategy.onFacebook:
                this.shareStrategy = new ShareOnFacebook();
                break;
            case ShareStrategy.onInstagram:
                this.shareStrategy = new ShareOnInstagram();
                break;
            case ShareStrategy.onTwitter:
                this.shareStrategy = new ShareOnTwitter();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void SharePhoto(string photoName, ShareStrategy strategy)
    {
        if (!this.photosNames.Contains(photoName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid photo name.");
            return;
        }

        this.SetShareStrategy(strategy);
        shareStrategy.Share(photoName);
    }
}
```

This is The Share Strategy Enum

```
public enum ShareStrategy
{
    onFacebook,
    onInstagram,
    onTwitter
}
```

And the Strategies classes

```
public class ShareOnFacebook : IShareStrategy
{
    public void Share(string photoName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You shared {photoName} on Facebook.");
    }
}

public class ShareOnInstagram : IShareStrategy
{
    public void Share(string photoName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You shared {photoName} on Instagram.");
    }
}

public class ShareOnTwitter : IShareStrategy
{
    public void Share(string photoName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You shared {photoName} on Twitter.");
    }
}
```

Comment: We cannot review just the pattern alone. You have use it with some _real-world_ application. I see you have one so please [edit] your question and add a description about what it is doing.

Comment: Looks more like Factory rather than Strategy

Comment: Here's a more trustworthy example from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use dependency injection. Something like

```
serviceCollection
   .AddTransient<IShareStrategy, ShareOnFacebook>()
   .AddTransient<IShareStrategy, ShareOnTwitter>()
   .AddTransient<IShareStrategyProvider, ShareStrategyProvider>();

public class ShareStrategyProvider : IShareStrategyProvider
{
   private readonly IEnumerable<IShareStrategy> _strategies;
   public ShareStrategyProvider(IEnumerable<IShareStrategy> strategies) 
   {
      _strategies = strategies;
   }

   public GetStrategy(ShareStrategy sharingStrategy);
   {
      return _strategies.Single(s => s.SharingStrategy == sharingStrategy);
   }
}
```

edit: Read up on open/closed principle, its related